# Does a change in moveset change the CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I may use my TM's on my Pokemons but will a change in the moveset change the combat power of my Pokemon?

Answer (score 5):

No, the only way to change the CP of a Pokémon is either by evolving it or Powering it up.

Changing the moveset just means the Pokemon gets new moves to use in battle.